# jQuery Div Visible when unload event occurs

Tags: jquery, html, css, function, events

I have used an event where if a person closes the tab or window, it will create an alert box to ask if they would like to stay on the page or leave. I am able to get that part to work, but I would like to then set an invisible div element on the page to visible when that popup box occurs. How would I accomplish this? I understand that I can only return one value the way it is currently set up. Is there a way to have the div become visible, then return? Thanks.

Code:

```
$(window).bind('click', function(event) {
    if(event.target.href) $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
});

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(event) {
    $('offerWindow').css("visibility", "visible");
    return 'Press "Stay on Page" and get a special offer!';
});
```

Comment: What kind of element is `offerWindow`? An Id? a Class? You are forgetting to specify it.

Comment: Yup, just got off a three day weekend. I feel so dumb. It was a class element and I have since fixed the problem. Thanks. =)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue. It has been a long weekend and I did not see that I did not put a class selector. offerWindow is a class and I did not target it as such.